# Can't make my script fetch only the links from next pages from a stubborn website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've created a script in python to scrape only the links to the different restaurants from a website traversing multiple pages. I can see how many links are there by looking at a certain text located at the top right corner like:

***Showing 1-30 of 18891***

But I can't go past [this link](https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&start=960) manually or with script. The site increments its content by 30 in each pagination.

I've tried so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&start={}'

for page in range(960,1920,30): # modified the range to reproduce the issue

    resp = requests.get(link.format(page),headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})

    print(resp.status_code,resp.url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    for items in soup.select("li[class^='lemon--li__']"):

        if not items.select_one("h3 > a[href^='/biz/']"):continue
        lead_link = items.select_one("h3 > a[href^='/biz/']").get("href")
        print(lead_link)
```

The above script fetches me the links from its [landing page](https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&start=960) only.

***How can I get links from other pages as well?***

Comment: did you check these pages in web browser ? I can open page for 960 but when I press "Next" (to see for 990) then It shows message *"We're sorry, the page of results you requested is unavailable."*

Comment: Yeah see the same thing. I wrote a scraper for fun that pulls name, ranking, phone, address, rating and link if you want it. Still, seems like page is broken.

Comment: thanks, few months ago as a answer for similar question I created code which uses framework [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) to download images from this page: [github.com/furas/python-examples ... Yelp](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/__scraping__/yelp.com%20-%20scrapy/main.py)

Comment: pages use two SQL queries: first to count all results and second to get data for current page. If there are differences then first query can give wrong number. Or maybe they add restriction to second query. People rather will no visit so many pages but it can blocks bots which can block server.

Comment: Right you are @furas. But, I think when someone visits a page, he usually clicks on the last page button as well. However, I'm not talking about visiting from 0 to that many pages; rather, I'm talking about visiting only the next page from the link I've provied above.

Comment: It seems like 1000 results is the cutoff for some reason? If I was yelp I might say "why would anybody go through more then 1000 results unless they are scraping". Haha.

Comment: I would suggest maybe get a database of suburbs and break it down like that: https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=&find_loc=North%20Brookline%2C%20Boston%2C%20MA

Comment: Most website limit # of search results to avoid scraping as well improve user experience. So there is nothing technology will help you on this

Comment: There is a button named `All Filters` in the top left corner in which there are the list of `Neighborhoods`. They are static and can be parsed using requests. So, if you make use of those `Neighborhoods`, there is a great chance you can get most of the results. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data after that page.

Your code should be modified to the following -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&start={}"

for page in range(0, 960, 30):  # modified the range to reproduce the issue

    resp = requests.get(link.format(page), headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})

    print(resp.status_code, resp.url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")
    for items in soup.select("li[class^='lemon--li__']"):

        if not items.select_one("h3 > a[href^='/biz/']"):
            continue
        lead_link = items.select_one("h3 > a[href^='/biz/']").get("href")
        print(lead_link)
```

Comment: If this is the only solution, I've already had it. Perhaps you forgot to read the comment I made at this same line `for page in range(0, 960, 30)`. However, I modified the range intentionally to reproduce the issue. Thanks.

Comment: There is no data beyond that range. 
That is why you are not finding links.

If you go to - [link](https://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=Restaurants&find_loc=New%20York%2C%20NY&start=990) you will see it says "We're sorry, the page of results you requested is unavailable."

Answer (score 0):

Yelp is intentionally blocking you from doing this, trying to avoid just the thing you are doing, as I expect a lot of people try writing crawlers for their site.

https://www.yelp.com/robots.txt even has a whimsical intro and specifically mentions crawling, and that you should contact them.

So either you contact them if you really need the data, or try other things that might slip through the cracks, like filtering for suburbs as suggested in comments.

Anyway, the simple answer is that what you are trying to do is not allowed by yelp, so in this way, not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Endre Borza. I've noticed several times that when a question has no answer or difficult to answer then this ***do's and don'ts*** thing come up otherwise how restricted that site is there is always a solution I get.

Answer (score 0):

The specific search parameters has only 24 pages in the site and i recommend to check if there is a next page from [image: html section containing links to pages]

this will prevent you from making requests to non existent results as you can see the last page for the link you sent is [image: the last page for the link sent]

if you get a 403 or a similar error then set user agent header and other headers you can also use the [requestez](https://pypi.org/project/requestez/) library which automatically sets these headers.